# PowerShell, itextsharp extracted text no more readable ( script was fine before )

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, itext

I was using a **PowerShell** script with ***itextsharp***   to extract some datas from accounting PDFs to organize the renamed files ( with extracted datas ) on the webserver database...
Everything was working fine until recently :
The extracted text is no more readable ; i have symbols like

```
!9H#SH!#!T !a!ST^ET
8%’?E!8A8A,A ;B;0D3FD
U+.0’$=Q$;L?L\$’($4-R$2’$4+(.’R.-./+($D$
%M%G.T
```

I imagine it has something to do with a new encoding way after an update of the accounting software.
A simple script like below was working

```
function convert-PDFtoText {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$file
    )   
    Add-Type -Path "C:\PathTo\itextsharp.dll"
    $pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $file
    for ($page = 1; $page -le $pdf.NumberOfPages; $page++){
        $text=[iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf,$page)
        Write-Output $text
    }   
    $pdf.Close()
}

$file = "C:\ADA3_FA20210274.pdf"

convert-PDFtoText $file
```

It doesn't work on those new PDF files. 
If someone could show me the way to handle that, i would be gratfull
I use itextsharp 5.5.13.2

Edit:
Here a link to one of those PDF :[pdf_exemple.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHoD2yiVhlTKbc8o2N5keuLjw1djgI9N/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like the PDF's are no longer textual, but images instead.. You should contact the provider of the accounting system to find out what they have changed there.

Comment: @Theo, Thank you for your answerd, but i don't think so : The file size are about the same, i can coppy / past the text from a PDF reader ( like firefox ) to a txt file, so i doubt it was converted to image. I keep digging

Comment: I'm afraid we'd need an example of the new, unparsable PDFs.

Comment: @mkl , A link to one of those "unparsable PDF" has been added.. BTW trying with pdftotext.exe give me " Illegal entry in Unicode CMap", and produce the same unreadable characters. TY for your time.

Comment: A quick test - trying copy&paste from Adobe Reader - also results in those unreadable characters. So this does indeed look like something is fishy inside the pdf. I'll look more closely later.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Short

As already pointed out by `pdftotext.exe` there are *Illegal entries in Unicode CMap*. More exactly, **all** entries in the ToUnicode maps of the fonts in your PDF are invalid. Thus, it is not a bug in a text extractor if it fails to extract the text from your document. Some parsers, though, apparently parse the maps in a way that they ignore the errors.

#### In Detail

PDFs are foremost made for PDF *viewers*, so font definitions in PDFs merely have to provide a mapping from the codes used in string arguments of text showing instructions to a glyph drawing definition, e.g. in a ttf stream embedded in the pdf. In particular they don't need to provide a mapping from those codes to *Unicode characters*. Thus, that the PDFs display properly does not mean that text can be extracted from them.

A PDF *can* provide mappings from those codes to Unicode characters in so called **ToUnicode** maps. And in case of your PDF such maps are provided but they *all are broken*.

These maps in text form shall contain a **codespacerange** section that defines the nature of the codes, in particular whether a single byte or multiple bytes make up a code for a single glyph. Then in **bfchar** and **bfrange** sections single codes or code ranges shall be mapped to single Unicode strings or ranges thereof respectively. The codes and the Unicode strings are given in hexadecimal notation in angled brackets.

In your PDF these maps are broken. For example in case of the font **1** the **codespacerange** is defined as

```cos
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <FF>
endcodespacerange
```

i.e. as single byte codes from 0x00 to 0xFF. This is correct, the font is a simple font and, therefore, can only have single byte codes. But...

That font then only uses a **bfchar** section to map these codes:

```cos
66 beginbfchar
<0021> <0032#1>
<0022> <0036#1>
<0023> <0030#1>
<0024> <0020#1>
<0025> <0041#1>
<0026> <0076#1>
...
<005D> <0025#1>
<005E> <002C#1>
<005F> <004B#1>
<0060> <0062#1>
<0061> <00A0#1>
<0062> <0044#0>
endbfchar
```

and the entries in this section are *all broken*!

On one hand according to the **codespacerange** above we only have single byte codes but here we only have mappings for double byte codes `<0021>`, `<0022>`, etc. As the code ranges may also be mixed length, the code length must be taken seriously, so all these double-byte entries cannot be used for text extraction because the font does not use any double byte codes.

On the other hand all the values of these mappings are broken because they contain an illegal part `#1` or `#0`. Here a parser can immediately ignore the entries because it is unclear what this shall mean.

As a result many text extractors ignore these mappings and default to returning the codes as they are. In many PDFs the codes actually are in some common ASCII'ish encoding, so this default makes sense. In your PDF, though, the font encodings are not, they are different, non-standard, ad-hoc encodings. So you get merely gibberish.

PDF viewers that extract the desired text from your PDFs ignore the errors above which in other cases may cause them to extract gibberish where more strict extractors extract something sensible.

Thus, you should tell the maintainers of the updated accounting software about the errors in their PDFs and ask them to fix this.